# micropython - ESP32 - MQTT Exception 4 - Google Cloud IoT

Tags: python, esp32, micropython, google-cloud-iot

I am looking to send sensor data through an ESP32 board using micropython to Google IoT Cloud.

I found an implementation example here: https://nihal-pasham.medium.com/you-could-try-freezing-the-pyasn-1-9afd6533cd7a

But it is throwing the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 50, in <module>
  File "main.py", line 44, in get_mqtt_client
  File "umqtt/simple.py", line 99, in connect
MQTTException: 4
```

That's the board I am using:
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0718T232Z/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0718T232Z)

That's the micropython version I am using:
esp32-idf3-20200902-v1.13.bin

and that's my code:

```
from third_party import rsa
import config
from third_party import string
from umqtt.simple import MQTTClient
from ubinascii import b2a_base64
import ujson
import utime

def on_message(topic, message):
    print((topic,message))

def b42_urlsafe_encode(payload):
    return string.translate(b2a_base64(payload)[:-1].decode('utf-8'),{ ord('+'):'-', ord('/'):'_' })

def create_jwt(project_id, private_key, algorithm, token_ttl):
    print("Creating JWT...")
    private_key = rsa.PrivateKey(*private_key)

    # Epoch_offset is needed because micropython epoch is 2000-1-1 and unix is 1970-1-1. Adding 946684800 (30 years)
    epoch_offset = 946684800
    claims = {
            # The time that the token was issued at
            'iat': utime.time() + epoch_offset,
            # The time the token expires.
            'exp': utime.time() + epoch_offset + token_ttl,
            # The audience field should always be set to the GCP project id.
            'aud': project_id
    }

    #This only supports RS256 at this time.
    header = { "alg": algorithm, "typ": "JWT" }
    content = b42_urlsafe_encode(ujson.dumps(header).encode('utf-8'))
    content = content + '.' + b42_urlsafe_encode(ujson.dumps(claims).encode('utf-8'))
    signature = b42_urlsafe_encode(rsa.sign(content,private_key,'SHA-256'))
    return content+ '.' + signature #signed JWT

def get_mqtt_client(project_id, cloud_region, registry_id, device_id, jwt):
    """Create our MQTT client. The client_id is a unique string that identifies
    this device. For Google Cloud IoT Core, it must be in the format below."""
    client_id = 'projects/{}/locations/{}/registries/{}/devices/{}'.format(project_id, cloud_region, registry_id, device_id)
    print('Sending message with password {}'.format(jwt))
    client = MQTTClient(client_id.encode('utf-8'),server=config.google_cloud_config['mqtt_bridge_hostname'],port=config.google_cloud_config['mqtt_bridge_port'],user=b'ignored',password=jwt.encode('utf-8'),ssl=True)
    client.set_callback(on_message)
    client.connect()
    client.subscribe('/devices/{}/config'.format(device_id), 1)
    client.subscribe('/devices/{}/commands/#'.format(device_id), 1)
    return client

jwt = create_jwt(config.google_cloud_config['project_id'], config.jwt_config['private_key'], config.jwt_config['algorithm'], config.jwt_config['token_ttl'])
client = get_mqtt_client(config.google_cloud_config['project_id'], config.google_cloud_config['cloud_region'], config.google_cloud_config['registry_id'], config.google_cloud_config['device_id'], jwt)
```

I have checked my credentials to Google Cloud with other examples, and I am able to publish/receive messages with my computer, so it should be ok from that side.

As anyone encountered similar issues? Could you someone help on this please?

thx

Comment: do you connect to wifi before connecting to MQTT broker?

Comment: yes, I do connect to WiFi. I am actually able to post sensor data through a simple REST API.
The issue is for the CA root certificate I think
https://github.com/micropython/micropython/pull/5998